# Is it possible to use BackgroundWorker class with .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to port a C# console project that works fine on Windows to Linux with .NET Core.
I have created a project.json file, run dotnet restore and everything seems to work fine.
But when I run dotnet build, I get this message :

> The type or namespace name 'BackgroundWorker' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

According to [.NET Core API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker), the class BackgroundWorker seems to exist in System.ComponentModel.

Here's my project.json :

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
  "debugType": "portable",
  "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something... Why did you post your project.json?

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` seems like it was built for WinForms and WPF - in console programs you might as well use raw threads. But the sexy-new replacement is the Task Parallel Library (i.e. the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace). Have you considered using that instead?

Comment: You need to install the appropriate [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel/) as well. Unlike the .NET Framework, these "system assemblies" typically aren't. .NET Core is much more modular.

Comment: No I have not tried the task parrallel library yet, but I might have to considere doing so, thanks ! By the way, if there is another solution, I'd rather not modify the code :)

Comment: What's the point to use BW, which was designed to deal with synchronization context and background threads, in console application? Throw it away.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I did not manage to get BackgroundWorker to work, even after installing the System.ComponentModel package. It does work well with Mono, though. Anyway, I ended up replacing every BackgroundWorker with Tasks, as you suggested. Thanks again !

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the `System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync` nuget package as a dependency (not the `System.ComponentModel` nuget package). If you look at the [BackgroundWorker.cs file on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync/src/System/ComponentModel/BackgroundWorker.cs), you can see that it's nested under the `System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync` namespace.

Your project.json would look like this:

```
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
  "debugType": "portable",
  "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        },
        "System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync": "4.3.0"
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```