# Can't find BackroundWorker in the Toolbox of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, toolbox

For some reason, I can't find "BackroundWorker". It should be under Components but I cannot find it. I have updated my Visual Studio to the latest version and my project type is windows forms apps (.NET core)

Proof my BackgroundWorker isn't there:

[image: Proof my BackgroundWorker isn't there]

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41882980/8967612) will work for WinForms, but really you should use tasks and `async/await` instead. See [this amazing blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) by Stephen Cleary for guidance on how to migrate from BackgroundWorker to `Task.Run()`.

Comment: Im in my repository folder right now and I don't even see my project.json file, sorry if I'm really new, im just trying to follow a basic tutorial as one of my first projects

Comment: One of the reasons could be that the component is named `BackGroundWorker`, not `BackroundWorker`. You also need to have the Designer of a Form opened.

Comment: Is that tutorial for .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: @Jimi that was not the problem haha sorry I spelled it wrong for the screenshot

Comment: Hmm, @41686d6564 actually now that I look back I see that it was .NET framework, but I only saw .NET core so I assumed it was the same thing.

Comment: You spelled it wrong also in the body of the question. Consider what @41686d6564  told you in the first comment. Tasks + `IProgress<T>` work very well and it's as simple as a BGW.

Comment: I think the problem may be that I'm using .NET Core instead of the .NET framework how can I get .NET framework? I don't see it when I open a new project

Comment: @Jimi ill check  Tasks + IProgress<T> out

Comment: A few simple examples and some notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449011/7444103)

Comment: If you're willing to learn a more modern approach for running background tasks, refer to my first comment. If you have to follow this tutorial for some reason, then yes, you should target .NET Framework. I'm not sure if VS can be installed without .NET Framework (if so, you probably would've had to manually unselect it). Perhaps just the template is missing. If you can't find `Windows Forms Application` when starting a new project, you might need to click on the `Install more tools and features` link.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions! I think I need to learn more basics of c# and Vs before I try anything else. I will make sure to refer back to this when I need it though
Thank you both tons!

Comment: Is there any way I can leave a rep or upvote your solution? This was super helpful